# Understanding some points of "Lemma 10" in Royden "Real Analysis" fourth edition.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The Lemma and part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

My questions are:

1- What is the relation between that the intersection of a countable collection of measurable sets is measurable and $E_{n}$ being measurable, $E_{n}$ is the intersection of what sets?

2- Why $\{ E_{n} \}$ is an ascending collection of measurable sets?

Could anyone help me in answering this questions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $E_n$ can be written as $$E_n=\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^\infty\{x\in E: |f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta\}.$$ The inner set is measurable, as justified by Royden, and the countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable, so each $E_n$ is measurable. As for why the sets are ascending, just note that as $n$ grows, we're requiring the bound for "less" functions, so more $x$'s will be admissible. Explicitly, if $x\in E_n,$ then $$|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$$ for all $k\geq n.$ If $m>n,$ then this is also true for all $k\geq m,$ so $x\in E_m,$ too.

Comment: why as $n$ grows, we are requiring the bound for "Less" functions?

Comment: I was speaking pretty loosely. What I meant was that if $n=1,$ then we look for points for which $f_1,f_2,f_3,\cdots$ all satisfy the estimate. For $n=2,$ we only need $f_2,f_3,\cdots,$ and so forth. I thought that may be a more "intuitive" way to see the statement, but showing it rigorously, as shown in the post, is not hard.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it :)